# In the css file styles are not working accordingly

Tags: css, reactjs

I am facing a weird problem with my css. I have created a module.css file for Header.js component and written some css but only path styling rule is effecting not others. Please help me find the issue. TIA!

**Header.js component**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../../asset/css/updated/header.module.css'

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className='header-container'>
            <h1 className='header-title'>Some text here</h1>
            <svg width="130%" height="100%" id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 690" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="transition duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150"><defs><linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%"><stop offset="5%" stop-color="#56b5e3"></stop><stop offset="95%" stop-color="#7d58a5"></stop></linearGradient></defs><path d="M 0,700 C 0,700 0,350 0,350 C 136.8,427.20000000000005 273.6,504.40000000000003 456,480 C 638.4,455.59999999999997 866.4000000000001,329.6 1038,291 C 1209.6,252.4 1324.8,301.2 1440,350 C 1440,350 1440,700 1440,700 Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#gradient)" fill-opacity=".9" class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150 path-0" transform="rotate(-180 720 350)"></path></svg>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

**header.module.css file**

```
path{
    fill:url(#gradient) !important;
}
.header-container{
    position: relative;
}
.header-title{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is better to import and use your CSS module stylesheet like:

```
import React from 'react';
import style from '../../../asset/css/updated/header.module.css'

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className={style.header-container}>
            <h1 className={style.header-title}>Some text here</h1>
            ...
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1):

either you import css like this

```
import '../../../asset/css/updated/header.css'
```

without .module
or

```
import css from '../../../asset/css/updated/header.module.css';
```

and then use it in code like this :

```
<div className={css.header-container}>
  <h1 className={css.header-title}>Some text here</h1>
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [react official documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) header.module.css styles should be used in curly braces. so we have to import css file as `import styles from './header.module.css';` and use class as className={style.header-container}